# Why Bellman-Ford algorithm needs v-1 passes?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I have not seen a graph that needs more than 2 passes using Bellman-Ford so far. Does any one have an example that really needs more than 2? (the algorithm says it needs v-1 passes in worst case). Thanks.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) has (as its only example!) an instance where worst case requires |V| - 1 iterations

Comment: Because the longest simple pass could be `v - 1`, imagine a 4-node graph A->B->C->D.

Answer (score 1):

A more interesting example:
`G=(V,E)`, `V={1,...,n}`, `E={(j,1,2j), (i,i-1,1) for all j=3,...,n and i=2,...,n}`. (Each edge is a tripe `(a,b,w)` meaning from `a` to b and w is the edge weight/distance.)

The graph looks like this:
[image]

The distance to node `1` gets updated `n-1` times.

Comment: Thanks,  but i think the simple example is indeed the one in [wiki_page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

How many times actually depends on the order of visit, the best case is visiting the one that has the negative weight to broadcast in the first place, the worst case is visiting it in the last place (so you always needs many passes to propagate the negative weight to first-visited node).